# Web Sql select statement not able to extract third column

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/utLfkvay/1/)

I am unable to retrieve third value of the row  it  is showing undefined when displayed using alert box .What i am basically trying to achieve is insert 4 rows to table and retrieve them as required sorted based on a column

### HTML

```
<div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 4 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log Text,log1 Text)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log,log1) VALUES (1, "foobar","sa")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log,log1) VALUES (2, "logmsg","da")');
    msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = msg;
});

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length,
            i;
        msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
            document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;
            var book = results.rows.item(i);
            console.log(book);

            alert(book.log1);

        }

    }, null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here i make something very similar to yours, and here it's working. Here my Ids are like:

id integer primary key

So when I do an insert, I don't have to use them, I let web sql take care of it

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (log,log1) VALUES ("logmsg","da")');
```

Also, I use promises (the code bellow is using angularJs

```
self.query = function(query, bindings) {
        bindings = typeof bindings !== 'undefined' ? bindings : [];
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        self.db.transaction(function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(query, bindings, function(transaction, result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }, function(transaction, error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    self.fetchAll = function(result) {
        var output = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            output.push(result.rows.item(i));
        }

        return output;
    };

    self.fetch = function(result) {
        return result.rows.item(0);
    };
```

So I can use it this way:

```
return DB.query('SELECT * FROM registro WHERE dia = ? and mes = ? and ano = ? order by horario', [dia, mes, ano])
        .then(function(result){
            return DB.fetchAll(result);
        });
```

I hope this can get you some directions...

Answer (score 0):

Your [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/utLfkvay/1/) link works fine for me (with Chrome 39) - I'm getting 'sa', 'da' alerts after running it. So I think it's something specific to your browser or more probably your cache.

Have you maybe created LOG table without the log1 column at first? Maybe it's still stored in your browser, because

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log Text,log1 Text)
```

line is not going to override it.

In Chrome you can check WebSQL schema hold by the browser with ChromeDevTools and 'Resources' tab, take a look there and see if mydb/LOGS table have your log1 column and data in it.